# How can i login with twitter without opening a browser in android application?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

i followed the steps in this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/ and other tutorials and all i got is logging to twitter via browser , is there any way to login without browser like facebook ?? Thanks in advance